# How can I make my dropdown expanding with an animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I've created myself a menu. All works fine instead of a little animation I want to add to make it looking more smoth:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery(".menu-item-top").click(function (e) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("visible");
  });
});
```

```css
#mobile_menu {
    display: block !important;
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
    overflow: scroll;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 0 0 8px !important;
}

#mobile_menu li {
  list-style: none;
}

#mobile_menu.et_mobile_menu li a {
    padding: 12px 30px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.et_mobile_menu ul.sub-menu {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}

.et_mobile_menu .visible > ul.sub-menu {
    display: block !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}

.menu-item-top {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mobile_menu" class="et_mobile_menu">
    <li id="menu-item-199" class="menu-item menu-item-top"><a href="#" aria-current="page">Click to open</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-1424" class="menu-item"><a href="https://google.de" class="has-ripple">Google</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1426" class="menu-item"><a href="https://google.de" class="has-ripple">Google</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So how can I animate now the `<ul>` dropdown? I want to animate it down and back up with an animation too. I've tried some things but I'm not good enough to get it working.. Can you may help me?

Comment: just answered the same here few minutes back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55423058/slide-a-div-into-appearance-without-jquery/55423163#55423163

Comment: @kukkuz Add this to my example. You'll see that this destroys everything.

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/9cupdL2w/

Comment: See you example. The parent element is still that high as the childs. Now when I insert this into my example, I can remove the dropdown because it makes no sense anymore. The space is still there but the content is gone.

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/v67bs8hw/

Comment: Worked, thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Jo

You can use max-height property for animating

Like

```
.et_mobile_menu ul.sub-menu {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

et_mobile_menu .visible > ul.sub-menu {
    max-height: 200px; /* adjust it according to drop-down size */
}
```

Comment: The dropdown size depends on the content and content can change. So in this case not a good solution.

Comment: You don't have to write exact height but the maximum that the list goes off for example you can put it 1000px but it reduce the animation time....try.it

Comment: Tried it. The animation is from the left to the right what is strange.