# Slide a div into appearance without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using `onclick` method on a link in order to display a div. However, it doesn't slide, it simply appears. How do I make it appear with a slide effect without using jQuery. The reason I don't want to use jQuery is because I want the page to load as fast as possible.

```js
function view() {
  document.getElementById('topmenu').setAttribute('style', 'display:block');
}
```

```css
#topbar {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
}

#topmenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="topbar">
    <img src="/images/santorini-wedding-photographer-logo.png" style="float: left;">
    <span style="float: right;"><a href="#!" onclick="view()">MENU</a></span>
  </div>
  <div id="topmenu">
    some text here
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Just like the mdn gurus do it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#Examples

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using Javascript 
setInterval() and clearInterval() functions.
See code samples here
[JavaScript slidedown without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795481/javascript-slidedown-without-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply *transition* to `display` property - you can *transition* `scale` instead - see demo below:

```js
function view() {
  // add a class to show the element
  document.getElementById('topmenu').classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
#topbar {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
}

#topmenu {
  transform: scaleY(0); /* scale to zero vertically */
  transform-origin: top; /* set origin to top */
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: transform 1s; /* apply transition to only scale */
}

#topmenu.show {
  transform: scaleY(1); /* scale to full height */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="topbar">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" style="float: left;">
    <span style="float: right;"><a href="#!" onclick="view()">MENU</a></span>
  </div>
  <div id="topmenu">
    some text here
  </div>
</header>
```